# How to zoomIn, zoomOut on onclick event in React Three.js?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, three.js, react-three-fiber

I have a `react-three-fiber` app and I'm using `OrbitControls` as my camera controls.

I want to use buttons on screen to manually **zoom in/zoom out** but I can't get my code to work.

I want these buttons to work the same way as how the middle mouse button works with `OrbitControls`. Does anyone how to make this work using `React`?

I tried changing the camera position using the `useThree()` hook but it was not working as I wanted.

Thanks.

```
const ThreedView = () => { 

const theme = useTheme();

return (
    <Grid container spacing={gridSpacing}>       
                
                   
                           
            
            <Box sx={{ width: 1, height: "70vh" }} >
                <Canvas>
                    <Suspense fallback={<CanvasLoader />}>
                        <ambientLight />
                        <pointLight />
                        <OrbitControls
                            //ref={camera}
                            enableZoom={true}
                            enablePan={true}
                            autoRotate={false}
                            maxPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
                            minPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
                        />
                        <PerspectiveCamera position={[0, 0, 5]} makeDefault />
                        <Preload all />
                        <Model rotation={[0, Math.PI / 4, 0]} />
                    </Suspense>
                </Canvas>
            </Box>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>

)}
```